# Deploying and Initializing anchor-escrow contract on devnet

Tags: solana

this is more of a question than an actual issue
I want to use the contract
`https://github.com/ironaddicteddog/anchor-escrow`
to exchange tokens.
My plan is as follows, however I'm unsuccessful initializing the contract.

```
logs: [
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]',
    'Create Account: account Address { address: 2yTRYBq58ZMgudQcEp18UnsCBPTUx9a12ZnzZ7N7v9hQ, base: None } already in use',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 failed: custom program error: 0x0'
  ]
```

Note: `2yTRYBq58ZMgudQcEp18UnsCBPTUx9a12ZnzZ7N7v9hQ` is the contract address in the `lib.rs`

1. Deploy program ✅ `2yTRYBq58ZMgudQcEp18UnsCBPTUx9a12ZnzZ7N7v9hQ`
2. Create `Token A` `DhS6x9pTrfCeY8iwkRdGstxUuphbeHqddT2vZSWRw3d2` and `Token B` `HpdLmjjxD8YZav2S1aastqyLsKDUb1ToLDfq4hPsLBoc` ✅
3. Create token accounts Token A account `Cj6cMp4xfAaCFegMg9G7GQaZWqYbQqgmu7Vjd4BbGYHh`, Token B account `HpdLmjjxD8YZav2S1aastqyLsKDUb1ToLDfq4hPsLBoc`✅
4. Initialize contract ❌.
5. Exchange tokens

I've written following script to initialize the contract.

```js
import * as anchor from '@project-serum/anchor';
import { PublicKey, SystemProgram, Transaction, Connection, Commitment } from '@solana/web3.js';
import { TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, Token } from "@solana/spl-token";
import { 
    escrowAccount, 
    initializerMainAccount, 
    initializerTokenAccountA, 
    initializerTokenAccountB, 
    mintAPublicKey, 
    mintBPublicKey } from './accounts'
import NodeWallet from '@project-serum/anchor/dist/cjs/nodewallet';

const takerAmount = 1000;
const initializerAmount = 500;

const commitment: Commitment = 'processed';
const connection = new Connection('https://api.devnet.solana.com', { commitment, wsEndpoint: 'wss://api.devnet.solana.com/' });
// const connection = new Connection('http://127.0.0.1:8899', { commitment, wsEndpoint: 'wss://127.0.0.1:8899/' });
const options = anchor.Provider.defaultOptions();
const wallet = new NodeWallet(initializerMainAccount);
const provider = new anchor.Provider(connection, wallet, options);

anchor.setProvider(provider);
// Read the generated IDL.
const idl = JSON.parse(
    require("fs").readFileSync("./tests/keypair/anchor_escrow.json", "utf8")
  );
  
// Address of the deployed program.
const programId = new anchor.web3.PublicKey("2yTRYBq58ZMgudQcEp18UnsCBPTUx9a12ZnzZ7N7v9hQ");

// Generate the program client from IDL.
const program = new anchor.Program(idl, programId);
  
const initEscrow = async () => {
    const [_vault_account_pda, _vault_account_bump] = await PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
        [Buffer.from(anchor.utils.bytes.utf8.encode("token-seed"))],
        program.programId,
    );
    const vault_account_pda = _vault_account_pda;
    const vault_account_bump = _vault_account_bump;

    const [_vault_authority_pda, _vault_authority_bump] = await PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
        [Buffer.from(anchor.utils.bytes.utf8.encode("escrow"))],
        program.programId,
    );
    // DEBUG BEGIN
    // console.info(`initializerMainAccount: ` + JSON.stringify(initializerMainAccount, null, 2));
    // console.info(`Escrow account: ` + JSON.stringify(escrowAccount));
    console.info(`Mint A: ` + mintAPublicKey.toBase58());
    console.info(`Mint B: ` + mintBPublicKey.toBase58());
    console.info(`TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID: ` + TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID);
    console.info(`SYSVAR_RENT_PUBKEY: ` + anchor.web3.SYSVAR_RENT_PUBKEY);

    // DEBUG CONSOLE END
    await program.rpc.initialize(
        vault_account_bump,
        new anchor.BN(initializerAmount),
        new anchor.BN(takerAmount),
        {
            accounts: {
                initializer: initializerMainAccount.publicKey,
                mint: mintAPublicKey,
                vaultAccount: vault_account_pda,
                initializerDepositTokenAccount: initializerTokenAccountA,
                initializerReceiveTokenAccount: initializerTokenAccountB,
                escrowAccount: escrowAccount.publicKey,
                systemProgram: anchor.web3.SystemProgram.programId,
                rent: anchor.web3.SYSVAR_RENT_PUBKEY,
                tokenProgram: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
            },
            instructions: [
                await program.account.escrowAccount.createInstruction(escrowAccount),
            ],
            signers: [escrowAccount, initializerMainAccount],
        }
    );
}

initEscrow();
```

Long version of the error output is

```
➜  anchor-escrow git:(master) ✗ ts-node tests/init2.ts
Mint A: DhS6x9pTrfCeY8iwkRdGstxUuphbeHqddT2vZSWRw3d2
Mint B: HpdLmjjxD8YZav2S1aastqyLsKDUb1ToLDfq4hPsLBoc
TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID: TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA
SYSVAR_RENT_PUBKEY: SysvarRent111111111111111111111111111111111
Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0x0 
    Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]
    Create Account: account Address { address: 2yTRYBq58ZMgudQcEp18UnsCBPTUx9a12ZnzZ7N7v9hQ, base: None } already in use
    Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 failed: custom program error: 0x0
/Users/tuncatunc/git/anchor-escrow/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:3961
      throw new SendTransactionError(
            ^
SendTransactionError: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0x0
    at Connection.sendEncodedTransaction (/Users/tuncatunc/git/anchor-escrow/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:3961:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async Connection.sendRawTransaction (/Users/tuncatunc/git/anchor-escrow/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:3918:20)
    at async sendAndConfirmRawTransaction (/Users/tuncatunc/git/anchor-escrow/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/util/send-and-confirm-raw-transaction.ts:27:21)
    at async Provider.send (/Users/tuncatunc/git/anchor-escrow/node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/provider.ts:118:18)
    at async Object.rpc [as initialize] (/Users/tuncatunc/git/anchor-escrow/node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/program/namespace/rpc.ts:25:23) {
  logs: [
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]',
    'Create Account: account Address { address: 2yTRYBq58ZMgudQcEp18UnsCBPTUx9a12ZnzZ7N7v9hQ, base: None } already in use',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 failed: custom program error: 0x0'
  ]
}
```

This is a long post
Thx a lot in advance for writing this contract to guide solana contract devs.

BR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer my own question here,
I figured out that the escrow program is already initialized.
The error log says that, it cannot use the same escrow account to re-initialize.